# Entity Framework Core 2.0 Add-Migration doesn't create any migration files

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-core

Recently migrated from EF Core 1.0 to EF Core 2.0, and it runs fine.  Today I added a new table (code-first) and added it to my DbContext with:

```
public virtual DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
```

When I run a migration, with my DbContext in a separate project (remember this was all working before), the migration ends, but no migration files were created.  This was all working prior to Core 2.0 using:

http://paultechguy.blogspot.com/2017/04/entity-framework-core-migrating-and.html

```
PM> Add-Migration GradePremade -project Mfc.MfcRepositoryModel -verbose -context MfcDbContext -StartupProject web.xyz
Using project 'class.xyz\Mfc.MfcRepositoryModel'.
Using startup project 'web.xyz'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile C:\development\xyz\web.xyz\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\web.xyz.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\pcarver\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig C:\development\xyz\web.xyz\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\web.xyz.runtimeconfig.json "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\2.0.0\tools\netcoreapp2.0\ef.dll" migrations add GradePremade --json --context MfcDbContext --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly C:\development\xyz\web.xyz\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Mfc.MfcRepositoryModel.dll --startup-assembly C:\development\xyz\web.xyz\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\web.xyz.dll --project-dir C:\development\xyz\class.xyz\Mfc.MfcRepositoryModel --root-namespace Mfc.MfcRepositoryModel
Using assembly 'Mfc.MfcRepositoryModel'.
Using startup assembly 'web.xyz'.
Using application base 'C:\development\xyz\web.xyz\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0'.
Using working directory 'C:\development\xyz\web.xyz'.
Using root namespace 'Mfc.MfcRepositoryModel'.
Using project directory 'C:\development\xyz\class.xyz\Mfc.MfcRepositoryModel'.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider...
Finding BuildWebHost method...
No BuildWebHost method was found on type 'xyz.Program'.
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'ApplicationDbContext'.
Found DbContext 'MfcDbContext'.
Using DbContext factory 'MfcContextFactory'.
Using context 'MfcDbContext'.
Finding design-time services for provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'web.xyz'...
No design-time services were found.
```

No errors that seem obvious to me, and no migration files created.  I've done a Remove-Migration to start clean, but still no workie.

Comment: For grins, I renamed my database and re-ran the Add-Migrations.  Exactly same results.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I got the exact same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to mark a project as the start-up project.

Answer (score 7):

There is an issue within the .NET Core class libraries. The successful workaround is to put the following in the csproj file of the `Model` project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I tried a few things like removing all the tables and then the database, removing the migrations, etc. But none of it worked. Finally, this answer worked just perfectly.

Comment: is this fixed in .Net 5?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to update your `Program` class to look like this

```
    public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        host.Run();
    }

    // Tools will use this to get application services
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: The Program.cs for my web app does have this already.  I also have a Program.cs in my separate class library repository.  Note I mentioned a link in my original post of steps I followed to get a separate class library with a working repository; this worked fine prior to EF Core 2.0 and VS 2017 15.x.

Comment: @user2737646 are you using .NetCore 1.x or .NetCore 2.0?

Comment: I am using .NetCore 2.0, VS 2017 15.3, EF Core 2.0

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but none of the provided answers fixed it. After reviewing my `.csproj-file`, I found that Visual Studio automatically added the following lines at some point:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="Migrations\**" />
  <Content Remove="Migrations\**" />
  <EmbeddedResource Remove="Migrations\**" />
  <None Remove="Migrations\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After removing this `ItemGroup`, updating my database worked correctly again.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all your `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>` implementations from your migrations project and register your `DbContext` in your `ConfigureServices` method in your startup class, the same way you would register when running the application.

Then run your migrations commands as usual, this worked for me after hours of headaches.

Comment: i think this one should work...... as i am trying to use sqlite instead of sqlserver

Answer (score 0):

Just try to review the migrations ModelSnapshot.cs file, for differences in the name of a table, creations of relationships (at the end of the code).

Answer (score 0):

DbContext class should have parametrless constructor and constructor with options. You have to Override OnConfiguring. Inside of it specified provider for exaple:

```
options.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
```

Code sample:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    private const string _connectionString = "Data Source=....;App=EntityFramework";


    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public AppDbContext() : base()
    {
        
    }


    public virtual DbSet<MyEntitie> Users { get; set; }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        if (options.IsConfigured)
        {
            return;
        }

        options.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

At the end use command line and run this command (type file name of project where is your DbContext file), alternativly you can use nuget package manager console:

```
dotnet ef migrations -v -p App.csproj add Init
```

Answer (score -3):

I tried updating the runtime version in the .csproj file to include:

```
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

in the PropertyGroup tag.  It worked for me.

See: [Russell Seamer's Solution](https://blog.reyno.co.uk/visual-studio-15-4-4-and/)