# add-migration is not creating tables in Database Asp.net core3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I set the Dbcontext class, StartUp class ,appsettings.json and everything seems perfect, even no errors when typing in console update-database and add-migration(code is generated).Everything succeeds but still tables are not created in database!! I would be grateful for any help.

[image: Output of running update-database -Verbose command in console]

Comment: Seems like you have an error "No design-time services were found" -

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `Update-Database -ProjectName final2019` or try setting the final2019 as startup project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851229/entity-framework-core-2-0-add-migration-doesnt-create-any-migration-files

Comment: how could i set the final2019 as startup project?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+set+as+startup+project&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB891GB892&oq=visual+studio+set+a&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4j69i60l3.5205j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: thank youuu! I reopen my project and it was done

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you have run Update-Database command after adding migration.

Comment: I did but still tables are not created